# Jibun dake baka o miru meaning?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I saw it on a prep book and there says the meaning is to waste time and money, but I don't understand how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

馬鹿を見る is a common idiom, but different sources provide different definitions to it...

> - to feel like an idiot; to make a fool of yourself​ ([jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B))
> - つまらない目にあう。ばかばかしい思いをする。ばかな目にあう。([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/174686/meaning/m0u/))
> - to waste time and money (your prep book)

I feel these definitions are not wrong, but insufficient. The basic meaning of this idiom is "to be insufficiently rewarded (for one's effort/honesty)", "to feel unappreciated", "to feel like a fool because something ended up with nothing", etc. Depending on the context, "to be left holding the bag" or "to draw the short straw" might be a valid translation, too. 正直者が馬鹿を見る is a common proverb meaning "Honesty doesn't pay."

自分 is "oneself" and can refer to anyone (I, you, he, etc) depending on the context. だけ is "only/just". Therefore 自分だけ馬鹿を見る means something along the lines of "Only myself/yourself/etc will be unrewarded/unappreciated".